# DTD must be defined before the document root element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, vb.net

I'm creating an XML file programatically. To create the starting tag I have the code:

```
Dim XDoc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Customers></Customers>
```

It's then followed by looping through the data, adding in the required elements using the Root.Add method. The XML displays in the browser successfully.

```
Xdoc.Root.Add(<customer>
                 <fields>
              </customer>
```

When some clients connect to this XML data, if there is no data to retrieve the page is displayed as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers/>
```

When reading the XML URL from a .NET project:

```
Dim Xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(UrlToXmlFile)
```

The error "*DTD must be defined before the document root element*" is thrown.

Although I can trap the error, I thought perhaps I may have done something wrong when creating the XML (XML isn't my strong point).

Some sites suggest adding a DTD (`<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">` for example). I don't know if this is correct or if I can ignore the error or if there is a better way to to declare this?

Update: when i view the page directly in Chrome, it displays the XML as

```
<Customers>
<customer>....</customer>
<customer>....</customer>
</Customers>
```

in IE it displays as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers>
<customer>....</customer>
<customer>....</customer>
</Customers>
```

but in both browsers when i look at '**view source**' it shows

```
<Customers>
<customer>....</customer>
<customer>....</customer>
</Customers>
```

I don't know of this would be an issue?

Update 2

```
    XDoc.Save(Sr)

    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml"
    Response.Write(Sr.GetStringBuilder.ToString)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
```

Comment: Remove the standalone attribute, that is only needed when you have a DTD and you do not.

Comment: I tried removing standalone="yes", i tried setting it to standalone="no" but same error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example showing the generation/saving and loading of your xml with no errors.

```
Dim XmlFile As String = "C:\\Temp\\TestData.xml"
Dim XDoc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Customers></Customers>

For ForCount As Integer = 0 To 10
    XDoc.Root.Add("<customer>Customer" & ForCount.ToString & "</customer>")
Next

XDoc.Save(XmlFile)

Dim XDocReader As XDocument = XDocument.Load(XmlFile)
```

Also it sounds like you might be using a web service.  Use fiddler to verify your web service is not adding in that attribute when serving the data.  I do not see how you are exporting the XML.  Make sure you are not just doing a `.ToSrting` on XDoc, that will only generate the inner XML.

Comment: Update: I added a StringWriter and passed that in. This initially resolved the problem but now i get the XML declaration including UTF-16 encoding (even though i am not supplying any) and the error "There is no Unicode byte order mark. Cannot switch to Unicode.". Reading on this error has a few workarounds but not sure if i can adapt one to my code or if i have to rewrite this?

Comment: StringWriter is by default UTF-16.  You can change it to UTF-8.  Do a search for outputting StringWriter with UTF-8.  I do not have an example readily available to show this.

Comment: What i did was Response.Write(Xdoc.Declaration & Xdoc.Tostring). I think this should be fine? There was no error after this (or so far there is non)